# Summary / Detailed entities without discriminator

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I want to have a single table where I can retrieve data using either a summary entity or a detailed entity. All data will be added using the detailed entity but often I just need a summary of each record for building a list and don't need some of the larger fields to be loaded for this for speed. I've tried the code below but it adds in a discriminator, which I don't want. How can I do this properly?
Ideally it would prevent records being added with the summary but I'm not so concerned about that.

```
public class Summary
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(254)]
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}

public class Detailed : Summary 
{
    public string BigField { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Summary> Summaries { get; set; } = null!;
    public DbSet<Detailed> Details { get; set; } = null!;

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Summary>(
            s =>
            {
                s.ToTable("Details");
            });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Detailed>(
            s =>
            {
                s.ToTable("Details");
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is called Table per hirarchy:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance#table-per-type-configuration

another solution would be to add the `Detailed` to the db and only select the needed fields in your queries

```
dbContext
    .Details
    .Select(d => new Summary { Id = d.Id, Name = d.Name })
    .ToListAsync();
```

this gets translated to the sql query:

```
SELECT Id, Name
From Detailed
```

and therefore you don't query all the data.

Comment: Table per hierarchy looks to be what it's doing by default but if I query Summaries, it will only return those items added as Summary (which will be none). The SELECT would give me the data I want but I want it to use a simpler class without all the extra fields and I'm using nullable compiler feature and don't want to make things nullable that aren't really nullable in dB.